# Browser back navigation resets session variable, but returns correct value after refresh (Flask, Firefox, Jquery)

Tags: jquery, session, flask

Browser back navigation resets session variable (Flask, Firefox, Jquery)

I have observed that Flask's session variable was resetted when using browser back button. In my case, I use a jquery .getJSON call to login the user, and save the login status in flask's session dict.

To keep the status up to date, i added another .getJSON call to query login state on document.ready().

Now i navigate to another page, click back button to go back to the first page, the user appears logged out. And in console i see the document.ready() login state query returned false, though if i refresh the same query will return correct login status.

I am confused how can this happen? If flask stores session values on client, shouldnt the status lost during back nav? why refreshing returns the correct value?

Edit: in the context of Flask + Jquery, how can i make sure a page always reflects correct login status witout refreshing?

Comment: please elaborate more on *how* you implemented the login process.

Comment: You need to provide the code for your login implementation. Without that, we cannot guess the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Flask, it is your browser that is showing you a cached page when you hit the back button. When you hit refresh the browser discards the cached copy and requests the page again from the server.

You have to include some headers in your response to tell the browser to not cache your dynamic pages. See [this post from Armin Ronacher](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/8/8/add-no-cache-to-response/#952cc027cf22800312168250e59bade4) for examples, he explains it very well and even shows a decorator implementation for this.

Comment: Yeah I found out Firefox bfcache might be the issue. It caches the DOM status when the page first load, all subsequent DOM changes were lost after "go to another page then click back button". I tried various solutions I found the only thing worked for me is setting no-cache and expiry headers in the HTTP response. However that disables all kinds of caching for the entire page. I am wondering if it's possible to disable caching for a specific part of the DOM?

Comment: I just figured out the solution: keep the page cachable but refresh the part of page on document.ready. It does trigger on back button with FF.